# IF() statement alternative in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, if-statement

I have the code for MySQL (perl):

```
UPDATE pages
SET rkey = rkey + 2,
    lkey = IF(lkey >= $key, lkey + 2, lkey)
WHERE rkey >= $key
```

I need to use this code with SQLite, but there is no support of IF() function. What I can do?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

For generic SQL you can use `CASE`:

> CASE is used to provide if-then-else type of logic to SQL. Its syntax is:
>
> ```
> SELECT CASE ("column_name")
>   WHEN "condition1" THEN "result1"
>   WHEN "condition2" THEN "result2"
>   ...
>   [ELSE "resultN"]
>   END
> FROM "table_name"
> ```

From http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html section "The CASE expression"

E.g.

```
UPDATE pages
SET rkey = rkey + 2,
    lkey = CASE  WHEN lkey >= $key THEN lkey + 2 ELSE lkey END
WHERE rkey >= $key
```

Another link about SQLite & CASE (with example of update with subselect) http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg09.htm

CASE can be used in UPDATE in generic SQL, but I have no info about SQLite support of UPDATEs with CASE

http://www.craigsmullins.com/ssu_0899.htm section "Using CASE Expressions When Modifying Data"

Comment: Thanks, but I need it in UPDATE clause

Comment: VeroLom, Just try it in UPDATE. CASE is part of basic expression scanning, not part of SELECT.

Comment: I've got SQLite thinking long time without result when I use the code "...lkey = CASE WHEN lkey => $key THEN lkey + 2 ELSE lkey END...

Comment: Updated. If the code doesn't work, you can try to use subselects with case

Comment: Hmm...I tried it into the sqlitebrowser and it works properly but I've got a long time waiting when I tried it into the Perl.

Answer (score 11):

SQLite version 3.32.0 and newer support `IIF`.

> [iif(X,Y,Z)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#iif)
>
> **The iif(X,Y,Z) function returns the value Y if X is true, and Z otherwise.**
>
> The iff(X,Y,Z) function is logically equivalent to and generates the same bytecode as the CASE expression "CASE WHEN X THEN Y ELSE Z END".

---

E.g.

```
UPDATE pages
SET rkey = rkey + 2,
    lkey = IIF(lkey >= $key, lkey + 2, lkey)
WHERE rkey >= $key;
```

Comment: FYI SQLite version 3.32.0, which adds `IIF`, was released on 2020-05-22

Answer (score 7):

```
UPDATE pages
SET rkey = rkey + 2,
    lkey = IF(lkey >= $key, lkey + 2, lkey)
WHERE rkey >= $key
```

??? it to

```
UPDATE pages
SET lkey = lkey + 2
WHERE rkey >= $key AND lkey >= $key

UPDATE pages
SET rkey = rkey + 2,
WHERE rkey >= $key
```

Isn't it better?