# Insert with if condition

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I need to create a sql statement that does this work: let's say I have two tables A and B containing integer fields. What I have to achieve is:

```
if (!(C is contained into A)) insert C into B
```

I'm using SQLite. Thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [IF() statement alternative in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874285/if-statement-alternative-in-sqlite)

Comment: have you considered using transaction and performing the logic in the application layer?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Actually, in your specific case it may happen to be as easy as</s>

```
insert into B (c_value) select c_value from A where c_value = @your_c_value_here
```

see [INSERT statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

---

sorry I haven't noticed the negation in your question for the C in A condition
I have another option for you

```
with temp_val as (select @your_val_goes_here as val)
insert into b 
select val from temp_val where not exists
(select 1 from a where c = val)
```

check out [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/22f3a/7)

Comment: Good but there is also a '!' to deal with :)