# No such function: iif in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, case, iif

I have a quite typical task in SQLite.

**In case of X return Y, else Z.**

For such purpose I was using the CASE statement

**"CASE WHEN X THEN Y ELSE Z END".**

However, I found the IIF function in official documentation

https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#iif

> **iif(X,Y,Z)**
> The iif(X,Y,Z) function returns the value Y if X is true, and Z otherwise. The iif(X,Y,Z) function is logically equivalent to and generates the same bytecode as the CASE expression "CASE WHEN X THEN Y ELSE Z END".

But when trying to run said function, I get an error.

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: no such function: iif
```

What is the problem with this function? According to official documentation, such function should exist.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61826915/1553090) on Stack Overflow says that function was introduced in SQLite 3.32.0.  BTW, I found this by searching the web for "iif function sqlite" and it was one of the top results.

Comment: `case` is ANSI SQL standard and portable.

Comment: Don't bother with `IIF()`.  There is no reason to write code in SQLite that is backward compatible to MS Access.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @paddy and his link for this post [IF() statement alternative in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874285/if-statement-alternative-in-sqlite/61826915#61826915)

The problem came from SQLite version, which should be 3.32 or higher. I've been using SQLite Browser, and sqlite version was 3.25. I updated Sqlite Browser and was able to use IIF function.